# HTML and Javascript - ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I'm trying to create a user input where the user can choose a stock `Symbol`, a `Start Date`, `End Date` and `Interval`. I would then like for this information to be passed along the javascript function `api` to retrieve information about that specific stock such as `open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, etc. The javascript function is working and I'm being able to save the data as `csv` files as well (not shown in the code), but I keep getting the error:

```
let symbol = document.getElementById("symbol").value;
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at file:///c:/Users/Rafael%20Oliveira/Desktop/teste/tempCodeRunnerFile.js:5:14
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:169:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html><p>API</p>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="yahooAPI.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="symbol"> 
        <label for="name">Symbol (4 characters):</label>
        <input type="text" id="symbol" name="symbol" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="4" size="10" placeholder="Exemplo: TSLA">

    </div>

    <div class="interval"> 
        <label for="name">Interval: (1d, 1wk or 1mo):</label>
        <input type="text" id="interval" name="interval" required
       minlength="2" maxlength="3" size="10" placeholder="Exemplo: 1d">

    </div>

    <div class="period1"> 
        <label for="name">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="period1" name="period1" required
       minlength="10" maxlength="10" size="20" placeholder="Exemplo: 2021-08-20">

    </div>

    <div class="period2"> 
        <label for="name">End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="period2" name="period2" required
       minlength="10" maxlength="10" size="20" placeholder="Exemplo: 2021-08-25">
        

    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <input type="button" name="buttonExecute" value="Execute" onclick="api(document.getElementById('symbol').value,document.getElementById('period1').value,document.getElementById('period2').value,document.getElementById('interval').value)"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="table">
        <table style="width:50%">
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Open</th>
              <th>High</th>
              <th>Low</th>
              <th>Close</th>
              <th>AdjClose</th>
              <th>Volume</th>
              <th>Symbol</th>
              
            </tr>
          </table>
    </div>
    <script src="yahooAPI.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
import ObjectsToCsv from 'objects-to-csv';
import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2';

let symbol = document.getElementById("symbol").value;
let period1 = document.getElementById("period1").value;
let period2 = document.getElementById("period2").value;
let interval = document.getElementById("interval").value;

async function api(symbol, period1, period2, interval){
  const query = symbol;
  const queryOptions = { period1: period1, period2: period2, interval: interval };
  let result = await yahooFinance.historical(query, queryOptions);
  const resultWithSymbol = result.map((item) => ({ ...item, symbol: query }));

  console.log(resultWithSymbol);
api();
```

How could I possibly retrieve the user input data and pass it onto the `api` function in javascript? My main goal is to put the output in the `table` class, but I'd first like to figure out how I could have access to the data in my HTML file

Thank you in advance, any help is very welcome as I'm a begginner in both HTML and JavaScript (Trying to have a learn by doing approach)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows that you are trying to run the JS file with Node.js. This doesn't work because Node.js has no native concept of a document.

You need to load the JS into the HTML **document** with a `<script type="module">` element, and then run it by loading the HTML document using a web browser (pointing to an HTTP server, you can't import modules from `file` scheme URLs).

You'll also need to change your `import`s to reference the URL to the JS modules you want to import. You can't use Node module resolution in the browser.

---

Alternatively, use a [bundler](https://betterprogramming.pub/top-5-javascript-module-bundlers-for-2021-e6fe17657fb) to package all your modules into a single non-module script that you can load into the `<script>` element.

---

This assumes that `yahoo-finance2` can run in the browser in the first place. It might depend on Node.js specific APIs or try to access a service which doesn't grant [permission for browsers to access it cross-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header/35553666#35553666).

If either of those is the case then  you'll need to write server side code instead of using a client side script.